# Django template use inlinecss with variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using [inlinecss](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss) where this works:

```
{% load static inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss "/css/mycssfile.css" %}
```

But I need to pass a variable instead of a string.

It won't let me pass it with the context (I get "invalid file: None" error):

```
{% load static inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss a_context_variable %}
```

The same happens if it's inserted on the request object using middleware:

```
{% load static inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss request.a_variable_inserted_by_middleware %}
```

I've also tried using **with**:

```
{% load static inlinecss %}
{% with request.a_variable_inserted_by_middleware as cssfile%}
    {% inlinecss cssfile %}
{% endwith %}
```

But get:

`Invalid block tag on line 4: 'endwith', expected 'endinlinecss'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Any ideas? (yes, I do have {% endinlinecss %} at the end of the file)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the end tag `{% endinlinecss %}`. Please check out the [docs](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss).

This should do it:

```
{% load static inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss a_context_variable %}
{% endinlinecss %}
```

Comment: I do have that tag, right at the end of the file. I just tried putting "endwith" after that to preserve nesting but that went wonky, giving me a IsADirectoryError for my bower_components dir, which clearly does exist...

Comment: How did you add the context variables? Via view context or context processors or something else?

Comment: Both direct context return and context processor.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to debug locally, adding a break point here: https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss/blob/master/django_inlinecss/templatetags/inlinecss.py#L46

...after you made sure, that there's actually something else than ``None`` added to the context.

Comment: Yeah I can read the var from request and print to console OK. Right, I'll try debugging and report back.